# Doesn't the append function return the appended object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming `this` is some existing block level element in the dom and `image` is `http://www.google.com/images/srpr/nav_logo25.png` doing the following does not work:

```
$(this).append('<img>').attr('src', image).load(function() { alert('loaded'); });
```

Should it be done as follows?:

```
$(this).append($('<img>').attr('src', opts.image).load(function() { alert('loaded'); }));
```

Or it should be done some other way?

Answer (score 1):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) returns the object you appended to, to get the object you appended in the chain, use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead:

```
$('<img>').appendTo(this).load(function() { alert('loaded'); })
                         .attr('src', opts.image);
```

Both versions return what was in the chain previously...but since you want to deal with the `<img>` use the `.appendTo()` form.  Also, for reliable results with your load, attach your load handler *before* setting the `src` as I have above.

Comment: what is `this` in the context of your example?

Comment: @Russ - It can be any element (that accepts children), same as the OP as asking for.

Answer (score 0):

No, **[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** returns the jQuery object to which you are appending. From the source (1.4.4)

```
append: function() {
    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
            this.appendChild( elem );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The source without a great deal more context doesn't show much, since you don't know what `domManip` returns.