# Attributes do not set up

Tags: jquery

Why does this not work? (*http://jsfiddle.net/J8n2g/*):

```
$('body')
  .append($('<img>')
  .attr({
    'src': 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif', 
    'width': '100%', 'height': '100%' })
  .hide()
  .load(function() { $(this).show(); }));`
```

While this works well (*http://jsfiddle.net/J8n2g/1/*):

```
$('body')
  .append($('<img width="100%" height="100%">')
  .attr({ 'src': 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif' })
  .hide()
  .load(function() { $(this).show(); }));
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new account for every question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177294/doesnt-the-append-function-return-the-appended-object/4177306#4177306

Comment: Merged.  If you are planning on asking some questions, it might be a good idea to create an account.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: after some rethinking and debugging through the jQuery code, I've got some more info. The jQuery attr function has some code to catch 'height' changes and pass them to the 'height' function. However this is not triggered normally. Note that this all works:

```
// 'this' refers to the img element (ie inside the .load function)
$(this).height('100%');
$.attr(this, 'height','100%', 1);  // 1 sets 'pass' to true -> the height IS called
$(this)['height']('100%');
```

While this just doesn't work:

```
$(this).attr('height','100%');
```

The latter one boils down (in the jQuery code after some ifs and thens) to:

```
elem[ name ] = value;
// Where:
// elem = the image dom element
// name = 'height'
// value = '100%'
```

Apparantly this fails...

**Original hypothesis I posted earlier** (**wrong**): I think jQuery is interpreting/parsing the height attr as an integer.. the % is the 'problem' then, because using fixed pixel size in the first example does work (as is using '10.1').

Btw this also works:

```
$('body')
 .append($('<img>')
 .attr({ 'src': 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif',
         'style':'height: 100%; width: 100%'})
 .hide()
 .load(function() { $(this).show();} ));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the  is not yet in the DOM when you are manipulating the attributes. In the second example, you have already added it to the DOM when you are trying to change the src attribute.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with it. If you have everything up and DOM-ready and try $("img").attr("height", "100%") it fails as well.

Comment: Yeah, probably true - I was just throwing something out there. It seemed pretty plausible

Comment: I must admit it was the first thing I tested as well ;)